# django application not working after i add watchtower logging

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

```
    import boto3
    boto3_logs_client = boto3.client("logs", region_name=AWS_REGION_NAME)

    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'root': {
            'level': logging.ERROR,
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
        'formatters': {
            'simple': {
                'format': "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] %(message)s",
                'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
            },
            'aws': {
                # you can add specific format for aws here
                'format': "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] %(message)s",
                'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'simple'
            },
            'watchtower': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler',
                'boto3_client': boto3_logs_client,
                'log_group_name': AWS_LOG_GROUP,
                'log_stream_name': AWS_LOG_STREAM,
                'formatter': 'aws',
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django': {
                'level': 'INFO',
                'handlers': ['watchtower'],
                'propagate': False,
            },
            # add your other loggers here...
        },
    }
```

Here i implemented `watchtower` logging in my django app
My server is running but when i view `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

This site can’t be reached

what can be the error ? am i missing something please take a look.

please take a look how can i fix this

Comment: Look at the server logs. There's no way to tell what's wrong otherwise.

Comment: My application not even working. showing this site can't reach in localhost

Comment: any updates at this issue? I have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

TLDR:
This only happens when you use `runserver` during development.
Add `'use_queue': False` to your watchtower handler,
or make sure you don't propagate `django.db`.

## Long answer

I did some digging and it's one of the weirdest problems I've ever diagnosed.
I don't even know who to blame for this one.

The source of the problem is in Python's `logging`.
Apparently there are some issues with threading so the `logging` [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L214-L235) decided that it will acquire a lock every time it tries to do *anything*.

During Django startup, [it will configure logging](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2/django/__init__.py#L19).
Python's `DictConfigurator` will [first acquire the lock](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/logging/config.py#L500),
then [clear existing handlers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/logging/config.py#L535),
which causes all existing handlers to [flush](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2192).

The thing is, Django will actually call this `django.setup` function twice if you use `runserver`.
The first time is during [management command call](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2/django/core/management/__init__.py#L394),
and the second time during the [wsgi application startup](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2/django/core/wsgi.py#L12).

By the second time, there would be two logs in `django.db.backends` on `DEBUG` level,
because Django does some checks during startup.

Now, `watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler` by default uses threading.
[It starts a thread for every stream it sends to.](https://github.com/kislyuk/watchtower/blob/v3.0.1/watchtower/__init__.py#L415-L427)
When `CloudWatchLogHandler` [tries to send logs to aws](https://github.com/kislyuk/watchtower/blob/v3.0.1/watchtower/__init__.py#L343),
[somewhere deep in botocore code, it will try to log a debug message](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/1.29.133/botocore/hooks.py#L238),
[which will also acquire a lock](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1744).

See where this is going?

When `CloudWatchLogHandler` flushes, it will [blockingly wait for all messages to be sent to Cloudwatch](https://github.com/kislyuk/watchtower/blob/v3.0.1/watchtower/__init__.py#L482).
Supposedly, it is handled by the thread that `CloudWatchLogHandler` started.
But that thread is blocked when it tries to log the debug message,
because the lock is already acquired by `DictConfigurator` on the main thread.

### Solutions

1. Don't use `CloudWatchLogHandler` during development.
   If you want to try it out, run a proper prod server (e.g. `gunicorn`).
2. Set `use_queue` to `False`.
   This way `CloudWatchLogHandler` doesn't use threads,
   and locks in the same thread would not block,
   [per documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.RLock.acquire).
3. Make sure you don't hook `CloudWatchLogHandler` to `django.db.backends`.

Comment: I had a familiar problem in a project that doesn't use Django, which uses different AI-related models and libraries such as torch, mediapipe, etc. (I don't know which one to blame). But use_queues=False solved the problem for me.